# Cannot cast reflection field into Map

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection

I was trying to get cast reflection field to Map, but it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.reflect.Field cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

How do I fix this?

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
open class Base {
    var inherited: Map<String, String> = mapOf(Pair("testing", "testing"))
}

class Child: Base() {
    var notInherited: Int = 100
}


fun main() {
    val c = Child()
    var inheritedMap: Map<String, String> = c.javaClass.superclass.getDeclaredField("inherited") as Map<String, String> 
    println(inheritedMap)
}
```

link to code playground: https://pl.kotl.in/xW8g4pNsX

Comment: What is the reason you need to use reflection in the first place? Is this property private and out of your control?

Comment: Had to add MDC log for multiple handlers with different inputs types. I am using reflection in the abstract class that the handler implements so that I only have to do it once instead of in every handler we have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `c.javaClass.superclass.getDeclaredField("inherited")`

That represents the actual field. The global concept. Yeah, you got there via `c`, but one you run `c.javaClass`, you've 'left' the instance behind.

You need to ask the field object to go fetch you the value for any given instance. add `.get(c)` at the end of all that, and voila.

Using reflection to access things you know the name of as you write the code is a bad measure - it should be used only if you've exhausted all other feasible options. You may want to doublecheck a few things, possibly go back a step and ask for advice on how to do whatever it is that made you think: I know! I'll use reflection! - There might be better answers.